# What does it mean to be divergence thorem applicable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

To be able to use divergence theorem, $S$ needs to be piecewise smooth curved, and $\vec{F}(x,y,z)$ needs to be continuously differentiable.

$$\int \int_{S} \vec{F} * \vec{n} dS$$ where

$$\vec{F}(x,y,z) = <yz\tan^{-1}(y^2 + z^2) - 2x, xze^{x-z} - 2y, \sin(x^2+y)+5z>$$
and S is the sphere of radius 1 centered at the origin.

How do I check if they are piecewise smooth curved without looking at the graph? And how do I check if $\vec{F}(x,y,z)$ is continuously differentiable?

Could someone show steps to checking?

Comment: $\vec{F}$ is continuously differentiable because each of its component is. What is $S$?

Comment: S is what we are integrating over, and why because of its components? What do they show?

Comment: I mean the surface $S$ here in your integral is not given.

Comment: Sorry, S is the sphere of radius 1 centered at the origin. But couldn't you just check with F without knowing S?

Comment: To check that a vector field is blah, it may suffice to check that each of it's components is blah. You might need to find a theorem. To show that each of it's components is blah, you might consider that each component is a product or composition of blah. For the surface part, the issue is that the divergence theorem takes you from the boundary of a shape to it's interior. Everything's got to be well defined and blah or blah on the boundary, the interior, and if I recall, in a neighborhood of the boundary. Check the theorems you have.

Comment: If you violate conditions to a theorem, you can actually calculate incorrect values, a la counterexample.

Comment: @Walter I already checked in my very first comment...

Comment: How did you check it though....

Comment: @BradyTrainor I'm sorry but what is this blah. Could someone here please just show steps to checking those conditions rather than just saying them in words? Please?

Comment: "Blah" is a placeholder for any condition you might want to verify a vector field obeys.  You can do this component by component because vector addition of two smooth fields does not result in an un-smooth field, and each component can be treated as its own field.

Comment: It really depends on your class. You might find in your text book a theorem to the tune of: "any of the projection, composition, multiplication, addition or product map of differentiable functions is a differentiable function". If you tell us the wording of such a theorem that pertains for your class, we could help to apply it.

Comment: sorry, it appears you need *continuously* differentiable, I should have phrased the previous accordingly.

Comment: What methods are you using to describe the sphere, or to show that a surface is peicewise smooth. How we may help you really depends on the approach that is taken, there are many ways to discuss these matters. For instance, there are several standard ways to describe the sphere. (Spherical coordinates, rectangular coordinates, implicitly defined,... )

Comment: @BradyTrainor when this example problem, my teacher was like first you need to check if they are piecewise smooth and check if check if $\vec{F}(x,y,z)$ is continuously differentiable. He then said since it follows all those conditions, the divergence theorem can be applied. He didn't show how he recognized that they follow those conditions. Couldn't someone tell me how he did?

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your question about why $F$ is differentiable.

It could depend on the development in a course or textbook. This makes the question more difficult. I may make explicit and implicit assumptions as I go. A lot of details may need to be filled in, but I hope you find it a decent outline of some main ideas that could occur in some particular approach to the problem.

I will assume that we know that functions such as

\begin{align}
\pi_1:\mathbb R^3&\to\mathbb R\\
(x,y,z)&\mapsto x
\end{align}

are continuously differentiable. For instance, consider the definition at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions

I am going to replace the word continuously differentiable with morphism, and not worry if I am justified in this.

I will assume that the product of two morphisms is also a morphism.

I will assume that if $f$, $g$ and $h$ are morphisms from $X$ to $\mathbb R$, then the map

\begin{align}
F:X&\to\mathbb R^3\\
x&\mapsto(f(x),g(x),h(x))
\end{align}

is also a morphism.

Thus, you may note that each of 
\begin{align}
f,g,h:\mathbb R^3&\to\mathbb R\\
(x,y,z)&\overset{f}\mapsto yz\tan^{−1}(y^2+z^2)−2x,\\
(x,y,z)&\overset{g}\mapsto xze^{x−z}−2y,\\
(x,y,z)&\overset{h}\mapsto \sin(x^2+y)+5z
\end{align}
is a morphism.

Finally, we note that $F=(f,g,h)$ is a morphism.